# JQuery Autocomplete List get Json Item

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-mobile

I use JQuery Autocomplete List. But I couldn't get data from local json file.
How can I do?
I want to search product field in my json data.

js func.

```
$( "#autocomplete" ).on( "filterablebeforefilter", function ( e, data ) {
        var $ul = $( this ),
            $input = $( data.input ),
            value = $input.val(),
            html = "";
        $ul.html( "" );
        if ( value && value.length > 2 ) {
            $ul.html( "<li><div class='ui-loader'><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-loading'></span></div></li>" );
            $ul.listview( "refresh" );
            $.ajax({
                url: "file:///D:/projects/phonegap/Genuis_Market/www/products",
                dataType: "jsonp",

                data: {
                    q: $input.val()
                }
            })
            .then( function ( response ) {
                $.each( response, function ( i, val ) {
                    html += "<li>" + val + "</li>";
                });
                $ul.html( html );
                $ul.listview( "refresh" );
                $ul.trigger( "updatelayout");
            });
        }
    });
```

json data

```
{"Code":2376,"Bar Code":"[ 7896194400046 ]","Product":" ACUCAR MASCAVO NATU´S","Stock":null,"Supplier":null,"Departament":"MERCEARIA","Price":6.99," ": ,"Weight":0,"Promotion":"0 Un"},
{"Code":2187,"Bar Code":"[ 8076809529433 ]","Product":" BARILLA INTEGRALE PENNETTE RIGATE","Stock":null,"Supplier":null,"Departament":"MERCEARIA","Price":8.35," ": ,"Weight":0,"Promotion":"0 Un"},
{"Code":1072,"Bar Code":"[ 7891095154296 ]","Product":" CANELA DA CHINA 8G","Stock":null,"Supplier":null,"Departament":"MERCEARIA","Price":3," ": ,"Weight":0,"Promotion":"0 Un"},
{"Code":2249,"Bar Code":"[ 7891150029606 ]","Product":" SHAMPOO TRESEMME BLINDAGEM PLATINUM","Stock":null,"Supplier":null,"Departament":"MERCEARIA","Price":12.53," ": ,"Weight":0,"Promotion":"0 Un"},
{"Code":1464,"Bar Code":"[ 7896005801826 ]","Product":"3 CORAÇOES EXTRAFORTE 500G","Stock":null,"Supplier":null,"Departament":"MERCEARIA","Price":8.49," ": ,"Weight":0,"Promotion":"0 Un"},
{"Code":1173,"Bar Code":"[ 7896209400771 ]","Product":"7 GRAOS INTEGRAL 400G","Stock":null,"Supplier":null,"Departament":"MERCEARIA","Price":7.99," ": ,"Weight":0,"Promotion":"0 Un"},
{"Code":1174,"Bar Code":"[ 7896002366250 ]","Product":"9 GRAOS INTEGRAL 400G","Stock":null,"Supplier":null,"Departament":"MERCEARIA","Price":5.99," ": ,"Weight":0,"Promotion":"0 Un"},
{"Code":1557,"Bar Code":"[ 7501001169374 ]","Product":"ABSORVENTE ALWAYS ACTIVE 8UN","Stock":null,"Supplier":null,"Departament":"MERCEARIA","Price":5.49," ": ,"Weight":0,"Promotion":"0 Un"},
{"Code":2403,"Bar Code":"[ 7896007541874 ]","Product":"ABSORVENTE INTERNO INTIMUS SUPER","Stock":null,"Supplier":null,"Departament":"MERCEARIA","Price":5.98," ": ,"Weight":0,"Promotion":"0 Un"},
{"Code":2401,"Bar Code":"[ 7896007541867 ]","Product":"ABSORVENTE INTERNO INTIMUS SUPER C8","Stock":null,"Supplier":null,"Departament":"MERCEARIA","Price":5.89," ": ,"Weight":0,"Promotion":"0 Un"},
```

Comment: it's not possible to read a local file using javascript due to security reasons
if this is mandatory for you, then try disabling web security for chrome

Comment: looks like you forgot JSON file name in `url: "file:///D:/projects/phonegap/Genuis_Market/www/products",`

Comment: json name is products.json

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because Javascript has no access to files system on the client. You can disable this feature in the browser but most probably it is not wat you want. Just run a local server and request your `json` with it. Keep in mind about [Same-origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).